# Within an if-statement inside of a loop, how can I get the children of an element and push them into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, this, children

I'm making a meal planning / grocery list application with JavaScript and jQuery. Basically, this is how it works:

1. The user adds recipes through a form. The user enters the name of the recipe as well as the ingredients associated with that recipe.
2. When submitted, each recipe is stored in a `<dl id="recipeList">` element. The name of the recipe is stored as a `<dt class="recipe">` and each ingredient is stored as a `<dd class="ingredient">`.
3. For each day of the week, the user may click on a "Plan a Meal" anchor. This brings up a copy of the `#recipeList`. When the user clicks on a `<dt>`, a `class="meal"` is applied to it and the rest of the list is removed.
4. The next step is for the user to click on the "Generate Grocery List" anchor. When the user does this, JavaScript should loop through each `.meal` and create an array, `#mealsArray`. JavaScript should then loop through each `class="recipe"` and check to see if the `.innerHTML` of it matches an item in the `#mealsArray`. It does this just fine, but **the problem is** after a match is found, it should get the children of the `class="recipe"` (i.e., the `<dt class="ingredient">`) and push them into `#groceriesArray`.

JavaScript will not find the children of the `<dt class="recipe">`. I have tried numerous ways of coding this, such as:

- `this.children`
- `this.childNodes`
- `this.children()`
- `this.children("dt")`
- `this.children(".ingredient")`
- `this.contents()`
- `this.find(".ingredient")`

It usually finds something strange like `[Object HTMLElement]` or returns an error message like `Type Error: this.children() is not a function`.

It seems like this so be so simple, but I have no idea what to do. I will provide my code below — apologies for how sloppy it is.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="addRecipeForm">
    <label>Name</label><input type="text" id="recipeName">
    <label>Ingredients</label><input type="text" class="recipeIngredients">
    <label>Ingredients</label><input type="text" class="recipeIngredients">
    <label>Ingredients</label><input type="text" class="recipeIngredients">
    <button id="recipeButton">Add Recipe</button>
</form>

<dl id="recipeList"></dl>

<div>
    <h3>Sunday</h3>
    <a href="#" class="planAnchor">Plan a Meal</a>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Monday</h3>
    <a href="#" class="planAnchor">Plan a Meal</a>
</div>
<!-- And so on, until Saturday -->

<a href="#" id="groceryListAnchor">Generate Grocery List</a>
<ul id="groceryList"></ul>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var recipeList = $("#recipeList");
var recipeIngredients = $(".recipeIngredients");
var planAnchor = $(".planAnchor");
var groceryListAnchor = $("#groceryListAnchor");
var groceryList = $("#groceryList");

////////// ADD A RECIPE //////////
$("#recipeButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var recipeName = $("#recipeName").val();
    var recipeIngredients = $(".recipeIngredients");

    recipeList.append("<dt class='recipe'></dt>");
    recipeList.children("dt").last().text(recipeName);

    for (i = 0; i < recipeIngredients.length ; i++) {
        $("<dd class='ingredient'></dd>").text(recipeIngredients[i].value).appendTo(recipeList);
    };
});

////////// PLAN A MEAL //////////
planAnchor.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dayInPlanning = $(this).parent("div");
    var availableRecipes = recipeList.clone();

    availableRecipes.children("dd").remove();
    availableRecipes.attr("id", "availableRecipes");
    $(this).parent("div").append(availableRecipes);
    $(this).remove();

availableRecipes.children("dt").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedRecipe = $(this);
    var para = $("<p class='meal'></p>");

    para.appendTo(dayInPlanning);
    para.text(selectedRecipe.text());

    availableRecipes.remove();
});

////////// GENERATE GROCERY LIST //////////
///////// THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES //////////
groceryListAnchor.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mealsArray = [];
    var groceriesArray = [];

    // Create an array of .meal elements
    $(".meal").each(function() {
        mealsArray.push(this.innerHTML);
    });

    console.log("mealsArray is " + mealsArray);

    $(".recipe").each(function() {
        console.log("Checking " + this.innerHTML);
        // Match the innerHTML of each .recipe to the items in the mealsArray
        if ($.inArray(this.innerHTML, mealsArray) > -1) {
            console.log("We found " + this.innerHTML + " in the array!");
            // Get the children of that recipe, and place them in groceriesArray
            // *** Not Working ***
            groceriesArray.push(this.children.innerHTML)

        } else {};

    });
    console.log("The grocery list is " + groceriesArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try cast this Dom Element as a jQuery Element:

```
 //so instead of this.children() use
 $(this).children()
```

and in this case if you want HTML it will be

```
 $(this).children().html()
```

but it will get you first child HTML only, you can try the followng to get for all:

```
html_contents = ""
$.each($(this).children(), function(){
 html_contents+=$(this).html();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to `$(this).children().html()`, but it still doesn't seem to be working. I put `console.log($(this).children().html())` inside the if-statement and it returns `undefined`.

Comment: as this one will return for first child, if you want to will need to loop over childrens and get .html() for each

Answer (score 0):

To explain this simply. They're two types of elements ***jQuery* Elements** and ***JavaScript* Elements**. `this` is a JavaScript element. jQuery functions only work with ***jQuery* Elements**. So to make it work, use:

```
$(this).myjQueryFunction();
```

so for you:

```
$(this).children();
```

---

#### In depth

When creating jQuery elements using `$()`, it does a few things. jQuery uses *[Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com)* for selecting elements. If what's passed into `$()` is already an element. It doesn't do anything. Of it is, it will turn it into an element. Depending on which of the two jQuery uses. It will *return* an element. This is a regular JavaScript element but what makes it so special? The jQuery functions can *only* be run after `$`. The reason is how you create chained-JavaScript functions using prototype:

```
//Kind of how it's created
$.prototype.children = function () {
    //jQuery's code to get children
}
```

This is making it so `children()` can only be run off of `$`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed it to `$(this).children()` and added a `console.log` inside the if-statement. `console.log($(this).children())` returns `[object Object]`. Accordingly, `[object Object]`s were added to the array. Do you know why it's doing that?

Comment: @Michael I fixed a bug in your program: http://jsfiddle.net/7hv7opjy/ But `$(this).children().html()` won't work because you need to put `$(this).children()` through an each